# Equivalent of Ctrl-W for IntelliJ Mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

The cheatsheet says that for expanding selection I should use `Ctrl-Up`, but it doesn't work for me on the latest intelliJ, with Mac OS X 10.7.4

What is the equivalent of `Ctrl-W` for IntelliJ in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Depends on `Preferences` | `Keymap`. The action is called **Select Word at Caret**.

- `Mac OS X` keymap: <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> (`Cmd`=`Meta`)
- `Mac OS X 10.5+` keymap: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> (`Alt`=`Option`=<kbd>⌥</kbd>)

---

See the official IntelliJ IDEA documentation: [Select code constructs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html#editor_code_selection)

Comment: with a Alt Down for shrinking block selection

Answer (score 26):

Select word: <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>Up arrow</kbd>

(`IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.3` on `macOS Sierra 10.12`)

Answer (score 14):

It's called now `Extend selection`, as mentioned before by default <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>.

`IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 (Ultimate Edition), Build #IU-191.6183.87`
`macOS Mojave 10.14.3`

Comment: Still the same as above. Checked again with: 
`IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1 (Ultimate Edition), Build #IU-193.5662.53`    
`macOS Catalina 10.15.2`

Comment: Opposite command is `Shrink Selection`.

Answer (score 1):

To get all functional you can bind 2 action into Keymap[Editor Actions]:

1. "Extend Selection" cmd+w [make more selected]
2. "Shrink Selection" cmd+shift+w [make less selected]

Answer (score 0):

you can select 'extend selection' in IDEA keyword setting