# Can you batch select text between quotes in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

Given the following Java code

[image]

On the MacBook in IntelliJ IDEA, I can hold the option key and mouse click 'n drag to select a block of text.

[image]

Is it possible to batch select just the text between the quotes all at once within a specific block of code, similar to Option+MouseClickAndDrag feature above, like this?

[image]

---

Notes added based on comments below

Cmd+W doesn't work since it expands the selection to highlight the full line, and eventually the entire code block.  It does not select just the strings.

Shift+Alt+double-click is a closer solution, but requires you to manually double-click each string.  I'd like a solution that selects them all at once.

Answer (score 34):

If you use `CMD/CTRL + W` multiple times, you can expand your selection from the current cursor word to the enclosed string, to current line, depending on how many times your press it. This is depending on where your cursor is, at the time, unfortunately.

This tripped me up when I first started, because I always thought I was closing a tab

Comment: CMD+W expands the selection to include the entire line and eventually the entire code block.  This isn't what I'm looking for (unless I'm using it wrong).  I'd like to select the strings only, nothing else, as demoed in the mocked screenshot above.

Comment: @TERACytE I'm on a windows box here so I can't confirm for your system, but CTRL + W definitely selects the current word up to current string for me. Actually, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513662/equivalent-of-ctrl-w-for-intellij-mac `alt + up`

Comment: You are correct in its function, but I'm looking for selecting all the strings in a block of code at one time, not each one individually.

Comment: Though it doesn't answer the question, it was exactly the answer to the question I was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a regex search to achieve this fairly easily.

[image: IDEA RegEx Example]

If you are looking to find and replace you can go select regex searching and search for this Regular Expression:

```
(?<=").*(?=")
```

This will select all text between double quotes.

Comment: This is a closer solution, but it highlights all strings in the file.  I'm looking for something that works within a limited scope.  Similar to the Option+MouseClickAndDrag feature noted in the question, but highlights only the strings.

Answer (score 7):

As of now, <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> expands the current selection on my mac.

What you're looking for is `extend selection` and `shrink selection` in the keymap.

Answer (score 5):

#### Use column select

You can cleverly get three cursors on the variable names, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> arrow over to start of strings, hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>END</kbd>, and then move the cursor back using the arrow keys.

For getting the column:

**Windows:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd>(Hold) + <kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd>

**Mac:** <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd>(Hold) + <kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd>.

To place caret at the end of rows: move caret to top row, clone down to bottom, and click <kbd>END</kbd>.

#### Change Multi-caret Hotkey

To add a custom Keymap, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, type `keymap` and click on the one with `Settings` as subtext. Search for `Clone Caret Above` and `Clone Caret Below`.

I mapped mine to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd> on Mac.

#### Bonus

Try holding combinations of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, and arrows for improved selection power.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best result I have reached by now.

You can divide in two steps:

1. Select opening or closing quote:

   - If line structure is identical before or after your strings you can place multiple cursors before or after your string, very fast with `MIDDLE MOUSE CLICK + DRAG` or `MIDDLE MOUSE CLICK + DRAG`. Then `CTRL + LEFT/RIGHT ARROW` to reach the double quote: [After Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkK3J.png)
   - Then you select the quotes with `SHIFT + LEFT/RIGHT ARROW`. **Important** you have to end with cursor [inside quotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL5Zk.png), otherwise future *shrink selection* will fail.
2. `CTRL + W` to extend selection to quotes and inner text.
3. `CMD/CTRL + SHIFT + W` to shrink selection to only the string contained.

**Note.** Unfortunately by now in Intellij IDEA you can't *find into selection*, otherwise there would be many tricks to achieve the same result.

Comment: In this case, you could skip selecting the end-quotes, just get the cursor just inside the last quote (or similarly just after the open) and then expand selection once, no shrink needed.  (Also note, I believe the W shortcuts may have been replaced by Option-up/down, for expand/shrink selection.)  The middle-mouse drag in the right margin is a nice idea to make it fast.